# How does spacing impact the globbing operator when used with a let construct?

Tags: bash, glob, let, arithmetic-expressions

Note: Generally it is advised to use `(( ... ))` over `let`. `let` is subject to word splitting and glob expansion, which is something you rarely want in arithmetic evaluation. Sources: [link](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2219) [link](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/let).

Regardless, I would love to better understand how globbing works within the following bash let-constructs:

```sh
$ set -o xtrace  # used to figure out what is happening


# This section shows that globbing is performed
$ b=2
$ c=4

# watch out: '*' is the globbing operator here, so * expands 
# to the files in the current directory 
$ let a=b * c # This line will expand to: 
              #     let a=b bcc declaration.sh let-basics.sh c
              # Only 'b' will be evaluated because the remainder
              # after 'b' causes a syntax error.
$ echo "${a}" 
2             # Only b was evaluated so 2 is expected


# In contrast, it seems as if no globbing happens 
# here, even though there is a match on the 'bcc' file 
# in this directory.
$ let a=b*c
$ echo "${a}" 
8
```

Why isn't the `*` evaluated in `let a=b*c` as the globbing operator?

---

I used the following bash version:

```sh
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: `a=b*c` passes word splitting unmodified. As arithmetic expansion happens before path expansion `let a=b*c` does what you want. While in `let a=b * c`, after word splitting, you pass 3 arguments to `let`: `a=b`, `*` and `c`. Each is evaluated as an independent arithmetic expression. `*` passes this unmodified and finally reaches path expansion... If you try, let's say, `let a=b 2*3 c` there will be no error because `2*3` is a valid arithmetic expression.

Comment: @melvio : `let` is - like `((....)))` and `[[ .... ]]` a _syntactic construct_ and not a builtin like, say, `export`. Therefore, the usual expansion rules don't apply in the exactly same way. In particular, `let` imposes arithmetic context on its argument.

Comment: Note that `let "a= b * c"` would work as expected (and as `(( a= b * c ))` because the single argument is evaluated as an arithmetic expression, not the 3 sub-strings of it.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet wrong. there is no arithmetic expansion there.

Comment: @oguzismail Well, just give it a try: `unset a b c; b=2; c=3; let "a= b * c"; echo $a`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Yes, there's no arithmetic expansion there. There is arithmetic **evaluation** though, carried out by `let`, but that takes place **after** all expansions are done.

Comment: @oguzismail So what? What difference do you make between "_evaluated as an arithmetic expression_" (what I wrote) and "_arithmetic evaluation_" (what you wrote)?

Comment: @oguzismail Oh, I see, you were referring to my first comment, not the one just above yours. OK, you're right, there is a typo, it should be arithmetic evaluation and not arithmetic expansion.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet You said *As arithmetic expansion happens before path expansion `let a=b*c` does what you want.*, and I'm saying that is wrong, as nothing in that command qualifies as a token that can be subjected to arithmetic expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how globbing works

*Filename expansion* replaces a *word* that is a *pattern* by a list of files matching that pattern. You can learn about it in [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html). See also [man 7 glob](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

> within the following bash let-constructs:

Just like with any other commands. `let` is not special in any way.

> ```
> # here no globbing happens, even though there is a match on 
> # the 'bcc' file
> ```

I do not see how `a=b*c` could be replaced by a file named `bcc`. What happened to `a=`? `=` is a normal character. `a=b*c` does not match `bcc`. For example, a file named `a=bcc` could match `a=b*c`.

> Why isn't the * evaluated in let a=b*c as the globbing operator?

It is, you just have no files to match that glob.

Comment: You should probably read again the question. @melvio never pretended that `a=b*c` could be replaced by a file named `bcc`. What they wrote is that `let a=b * c` (spaces) does.

Comment: Hm... `In constrast, here no globbing happens, even though there is a match on 
# the 'bcc' file in this directory.
let a=b*c` The "in contrast", is in contrast to `a=b * c`, the "here.....there is a match on bcc" - I think "here" is `a=b*c`.

Comment: You're right. My understanding was different but after reading again I see that yours is the correct one. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Renaud, @KamilCuk, @Ogus, and @user1934428 for your comments and answers. Your lively discussion showed me exactly what my thinking error was.

Allow me to explain... My ***incorrect*** thinking was that the globbing only happens to the right-hand side of the `=` character.

#### Incorrect

So I was ***incorrectly*** thinking the following happened:

```sh
$ b=2
$ c=4

# 1. We first apply path expansion to `b*c` (INCORRECT)
# 2. I have the file 'bcc' in my current directory
# 3. So `b*c` expands to 'bcc' and we have `a=bcc`
# 4. I have no variable 'bcc' so 'a' should become 0
# 5. Then I got surprised because the result was 8 and 
#    after some probing, I posted this question on SE
$ let a=b*c
$ echo "${a}" 
8
```

Step '*1.*' in the above code is wrong because the path expansion happens to `a=b*c` NOT to `b*c`. And, as @KamilCuk pointed out: `a=b*c` does not match `bcc`.

#### Correct

So the following happens:

```sh
$ b=2
$ c=4

# 1. Path expansion is applied to `a=b*c` (CORRECT)
# 2. There is no match with `a=b*c` in the 
#    current directory so `a=b*c` is kept 
# 3. `a=b*c` undergoes arithmetic evaluation to a=8
$ let a=b*c
$ echo "${a}"
8
```

To confirm, I placed the oddly named file `a=b-matchglob-c` in my directory.
Now, with this file in my directory, `a=b*c` will expand to `a=b-matchglob-c`.

```sh
$ b=2
$ c=4

# 1. Path expansion turns a=b*c into 
#    let a=b-matchglob-c
# 2. Arithmetic evaluation will turn that into
#    let a=2-0-4
# 3. And 2-0-4=-2
$ let a=b*c
$ echo "${a}"
-2
```